# add mysqli_query to a array from a function

Tags: php

I am trying to find out if I can update an array from a function call inside another function.

I have a function that has a lot of HTML that I think will need to be repeated.  Trying to find a solution to not repeat myself.

My initial function is a query to a DB that creates an array.  I break out of php and add HTML.

Commented section was original code that I am try to create a function out of

```
function singleElim_displayTeam_r1() {
    global $conn;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $arrayTeams = array();

    // if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //         $arrayTeams[] = $row;
    //     }
    // }

    createArrayRoundNumber("r1", $result, $arrayTeams);

    // print_r($arrayTeams);

    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        for ($x = 0; $x < $num_rows; $x += 2) {
            $y = $x +1;
    ?>
```

function call

```
function createArrayRoundNumber($round, $result, $arrayTeams) {
    switch ($round) {
        case "r1":
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                     $arrayTeams[] = $row;
                }
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

This is not generating the array.  Looking for help pushing array data to $arrayTeams array from original singleElim_displayTeam_r1()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your $arrayTeams in by reference. You need to add the '&' in front of the $arrayTeams in the function.

```
function createArrayRoundNumber($round, $result, &$arrayTeams) {
  switch ($round) {
    case "r1":
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $arrayTeams[] = $row;
        }
      }
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: BAM!!!  worked.  I am too new to PHP.  I was not aware of passing something by reference.